# Como utilizar ScrollView + Listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou criando um sistema de perfil para usuários utilizando `ListView` e `RecyclerView` e não estou conseguindo fazer o `scroll` funcionar. Atualmente ele funciona assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu não utilizo o `ScrollView`, ele só faz o *scroll* do `LisView` e a parte de cima fica travada. Quando eu utilizo o `ScrollView`, ele continua com o mesmo problema, mas funciona perfeitamente se eu especificar um tamanho para o `layout_height` diferente de `wrap_content` ou `match_parente`, como por exemplo: `500dp` .. mas ele não pega todos os posts, pega os que dão de acordo com a altura.

Não entendi muito bem, pesquisei em alguns sites e não consegui resolver esse problema, vi em alguns sites internacionais que não seria possível utilizar o `ScrollView` dentro de uma `ListView` e em outros dizendo que tinha como, mas não obtive sucesso, não entendi muito bem, será que alguém pode me ajudar?

O que realmente eu quero é que a list faça *scroll* junto com a página como demonstra a imagem abaixo, no caso estilo Instagram, Facebook entre outros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Script* do meu perfil:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    cardView:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
    cardView:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview01"
    xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profileuimage"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:border_color="#FFF"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%"
    app:layout_marginRightPercent="4%"
    app:layout_marginBottomPercent="5%"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ucStatus"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_offline"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="35%"/>

    <com.addfrases.addfrases.MyCustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#4C4C4C"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileuname"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileuimage" />

    <com.addfrases.addfrases.MyCustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ccc"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileuregion"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="30%"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileuimage"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_about"
        android:id="@+id/useraboutimg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileuimage"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="8%"
        app:layout_marginRightPercent="8%" />

    <com.addfrases.addfrases.MyCustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profileuserabout"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="60%"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/useraboutimg"
        android:allowUndo="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/separator"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileuserabout"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="SEGUIR"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_follower"
        android:id="@+id/followButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
        android:backgroundTint="#4B7AB2"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="65%" />


</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    cardView:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
    cardView:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview02"
    xmlns:cardView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.addfrases.addfrases.MyCustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/totalposts"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#414141"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="20%"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PUBLICAÇÕES"
            android:textColor="#4B4F54"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="8%"
            android:layout_below="@+id/totalposts"/>

        <com.addfrases.addfrases.MyCustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#34373B"
            android:id="@+id/totalFollowing"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="20%"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEGUINDO"
            android:textColor="#4B4F54"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="41%"
            android:layout_below="@+id/totalFollowing"/>

        <com.addfrases.addfrases.MyCustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/totalFollowerss"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#34373B"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="80%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="20%"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEGUIDORES"
            android:textColor="#4B4F54"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="73%"
            android:layout_below="@+id/totalFollowing"/>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<view
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="453dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.31" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"/>
    </LinearLayout></ScrollView></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Aqui tem um link mostrando uma tecnica usando o linear layout dentro do ScrollView é bem fácil de entender, caso não saiba ingles traduza a página com o Chrome que ainda fica bem compreensível a explicação https://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2012/02/22/smart-headers-and-footers-in-scrollviews/

Answer (score 1):

utilize a tag fillViewport na sua scroll

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Sua estrutura ficará dessa forma:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <!-- codigo -->


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sim, já tentei, o que eu quero mesmo é que a listview faça o scroll junto com a página, no caso desça junto. como acontece no facebook, instagram etc... quando eu coloco o <scrollview /> até meche, mas quando chego na listview ela trava e só a list começa fazer o scroll, quando eu não coloco, a parte superior fica travada e só meche a list.

Comment: Ah! Entendi. 

editei a resposta de acordo com sua explicação.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não funcionou, fiz uma gif mostrando o que está acontecendo http://i.imgur.com/iSCVdjA.gifv. Obs: Estou usando o seu código, quando eu coloco a altura do scroll como wrap_content o list não funciona, ele fica como se não tivesse altura http://i.imgur.com/2eCVBaK.jpg, não funcionou :/

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi direito, você quer que o ListView que esta contornado em vermelho na sua pergunta, seja uma ScrollView infinita até o ultimo post, e que as 2 imagens superiores fiquem travadas.

Se foi isto tente o seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ajuda.ajuda.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/x">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/c"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lista_jornais"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

O resultado foi este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas não foi muito bem isso, eu gostaria que a listview fizesse o scroll junto com a página, no caso se eu arrastar pra baixo a página vai descendo, e o conteúdo todo fizesse o scroll, mas não consegui, a imagem foi para demostrar como está acontecendo, no caso  só a parte de baixo está fazendo o scroll, a parte em vermelho, a parte de cima fica parada, quando eu coloco o scrollview a parte de cima até meche, mas quando chego na listview ela trava e só a list começa fazer o scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de fechar a tag do seu ScrollView. 
Ele só pode ter um filho.

Coloque essa linha no final do seu código:

```
<ScrollView/>
```

Comment: Olá, boa noite, eu fechei, só que aqui no post não apareceu por completo.